# (Symfony 4) How do I access the Liip Imagine bundle from within PHP code?

Tags: symfony, thumbnails

I want to be able to upload a file, and create 3 thumbnails from it and store everything on an S3 server.

I have my liip/LiipImagineBundle set up as follows:

liip_imagine :

```
# configure resolvers
resolvers :

    # setup the default resolver
    default :

        # use the default web path
        web_path : ~

# your filter sets are defined here
filter_sets :

    # use the default cache configuration
    cache : ~

    # the name of the "filter set"
    my_thumb :

        # adjust the image quality to 75%
        quality : 75

        # list of transformations to apply (the "filters")
        filters :

            # create a thumbnail: set size to 120x90 and use the "outbound" mode
            # to crop the image when the size ratio of the input differs
            thumbnail  : { size : [120, 90], mode : outbound }

            # create a 2px black border: center the thumbnail on a black background
            # 4px larger to create a 2px border around the final image
            background : { size : [124, 94], position : center, color : '#000000' }

    # the name of the "filter set"
    thumb_square :

        # adjust the image quality to 75%
        quality : 75

        # list of transformations to apply (the "filters")
        filters :

            thumbnail :  { size : [300, 300], mode : outbound }

            # create a 2px black border: center the thumbnail on a black background
            # 4px larger to create a 2px border around the final image
            background : { size : [304, 304], position : center, color : '#000000' }

    # the name of the "filter set"
    thumb_rectangle_md :

        # adjust the image quality to 75%
        quality : 75

        # list of transformations to apply (the "filters")
        filters :

            thumbnail :  { size : [670, 400], mode : outbound }

            # create a 2px black border: center the thumbnail on a black background
            # 4px larger to create a 2px border around the final image
            background : { size : [674, 404], position : center, color : '#000000' }

    # the name of the "filter set"
    thumb_hd :

        # adjust the image quality to 75%
        quality : 75

        # list of transformations to apply (the "filters")
        filters :

            thumbnail :  { size : [1920, 1080], mode : outbound }

            # create a 2px black border: center the thumbnail on a black background
            # 4px larger to create a 2px border around the final image
            background : { size : [1924, 1084], position : center, color : '#000000' }
```

This is the documentation I am looking at:  https://symfony.com/doc/2.0/bundles/LiipImagineBundle/basic-usage.html#runtime-options

The problem I am having is that in the documentation it just says to do it like the following:

`$this['imagine']->filter('/relative/path/to/image.jpg', 'my_thumb')`

The obvious error I am getting is:

`Cannot use object of type App\Controller\CreatorDashboard\PostsController as array`

I understand why I am getting the error, it thinks I'm trying to use my controller class as an array.

But how do you access this Liip/LiipImagineBundle in the code then?  How do I get a "handle" on it in Symfony 4?

The documentation isn't clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example you shared is for template usage without twig. If you're in a controller (an assumption based on the error you shared) you need to get the Liip Cache Manager off of container.

```
/** @var CacheManager */
$imagineCacheManager = $this->get('liip_imagine.cache.manager'); // gets the service from the container

/** @var string */
$resolvedPath = $imagineCacheManager->getBrowserPath('/relative/path/to/image.jpg', 'my_thumb'); // resolves the stored path
```

Comment: Thanks harmstyler, that worked.  I was wondering, how do you get that to work in a service class?  Because I want to follow best practices and keep the controller as light as possible.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#choose-a-specific-service
You have to pass it as an argument with the id `liip_imagine.cache.manager`

Answer (score 3):

(tested in Symfony 5)
if you want to use it in service for intance (or in controller) you could inject the **Liip\ImagineBundle\Imagine\Cache\CacheManager**
and use it within your class:

```
public function __construct(UploaderHelper $uploaderHelper, CacheManager $cacheManager)
{
    $this->uploaderHelper = $uploaderHelper;
    $this->cacheManager = $cacheManager;
}   
public function getImageLink($image)
{
    $imagePath = $this->uploaderHelper->asset($image, 'imageFile');
    $imageLink = $this->cacheManager->getBrowserPath($imagePath, $imagine_filter);
    return $imageLink;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The use of `$this['imagine']` appears to only be when using it in a PHP-template. For using it within a controller, or service, you would [use it as a service](https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle#use-as-a-service), either by getting it from the container (the old style of using a service), injecting it manually into a class (in the service.yaml file with `@liip_imagine.service.filter`), or using the class-as-a-service-name that it provides, in the same way you would type-hint anything from the Request objec, LoggerInterface, or most other things in Symfony 3.3+ (from the code, that appears to the `Liip\ImagineBundle\Service\FilterService` class).

Answer (score 0):

also tested with Symfony 6.3 and liip/imagine-bundle 2.11

```
<?php
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Liip\ImagineBundle\Imagine\Cache\CacheManager;

class ItemController extends AbstractController{
    public function __construct(private readonly CacheManager $imagineCacheManager) {}

    #[Route('/list', name: 'list')]
    public function list(): Response {
        $pathRelative = '/uploads/images/image.png';
        $resolvedPath = $this->imagineCacheManager->generateUrl($pathRelative, 'my_thumb');
        $htmlString = '<img src="'.$resolvedPath.'" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail"   alt="..." >';
        return $this->render('item/list.html.twig', ['htmlString' => $htmlString,]);
    }
}
```