# bundle's service (autowire) not available in controller's method

Tags: symfony

I'd like to use https://github.com/tedious/TedivmStashBundle bundle in my symfony 4 project. Added by composer, configured in */config/stash.yaml* file and according to the profiler bar, it's working basically.

Now, I want to use to caching values in my controller. I've try to add the service *stash* by its name to the method's parameter, using the same name as the example says:

```
$pool = $this->container->get('stash');
```

but the framework did not find the service. It can't be added like the example explained neither.

How can I use this bundle as a service (autowired) in my symfony 4 app?

**UPDATE**

services.yaml:

```
  stash.default_cache:
    class: Tedivm\StashBundle\Service\CacheService
    public: true
    arguments:
      $name: 'stash'

  Tedivm\StashBundle\Service\CacheService: '@stash.default_cache'
```

Controller:

```
public function something(Request $request, CacheService $service, ...
```

It's looks like working now :)

Thanx for the suggestion (and the correct solution later) to @Cerad

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access Liip Imagine bundle from Controller - assign service to variable (Symfony 4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56528116/access-liip-imagine-bundle-from-controller-assign-service-to-variable-symfony)

Comment: You are trying to get the service from the container, which is the **opposite** from autowiring.

Comment: Start by running "bin/console debug:container stash" and seeing what class is being used.  Next, add an alias for the class to your config/services.yaml.  Then typehint against the class in your controller's action method.  If these steps seem confusing to you then start working your way through the service container chapter in the Symfony docs.  The example in the stash bundle's readme file definitely needs a bit of updating.  You should submit a PR once you have it working.

Comment: Class CacheService:
  Service ID:       stash.default_cache; 
  Class:            Tedivm\StashBundle\Service\CacheService; 
  Tags:             -; 
  Public:           no; 
  Synthetic:        no; 
  Lazy:             no; 
  Shared:           yes; 
  Abstract:         no; 
  Autowired:        no; 
  Autoconfigured:   no;

Comment: I try to add as alias, not working yet, but i'm on it

Comment: @msg and Alexandre thank you, but I can't modify my controller to abstractController :(

Comment: @yivi I've just tried that too. So my first attempt was to use the service like an autowired one (as method's parameter)

Comment: The point is not *using* `AbstractController`, but subscribe to the service if you want to retrieve it from the container. However, the preferred method is using injection. You should post all relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how to approach this sort of problem when dealing with bundles that are not quite ready for autowire.

Start by installing a test project:

```
symfony new --full stash --version=lts
composer require tedivm/stash-bundle
```

Note that the bundle does not directly support Symfony 5 hence the lts.  Note also that the bundles does not support Flex so you have to add your own config/packages/stash.yaml file per the bundle's readme file.

```
# config/packages/stash.yaml
stash:
  drivers: [ FileSystem ]
  FileSystem: ~
```

At this point we can determine which service we need to inject:

```
bin/console debug:container stash
Information for Service "stash.default_cache"
=============================================

 Class CacheService

 ---------------- ----------------------------------------- 
  Option           Value                                    
 ---------------- ----------------------------------------- 
  Service ID       stash.default_cache                      
  Class            Tedivm\StashBundle\Service\CacheService
```

Most of the time you would like to use an interface for injection but a peek at the source code reveals that the bundle does not use interfaces.  As a side note, calling a third party service 'stash' is not a good idea.  It really should have been 'tedivm.stash'  but I digress.

We can now create an alias and then typehint against it:

```
# config/services.yaml
    Tedivm\StashBundle\Service\CacheService : '@stash' # alias for typehinting

# Controller class
    public function index(CacheService $cacheService)
    {
        return new Response('Cache ' . get_class($cacheService));
    }
```

And that should do it.